# How to keep an application on top of all others on windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp, always-on-top

Is there a way to put any application I want on top of all others?
I'm on a windows XP machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [DeskPins](http://users.forthnet.gr/pat/efotinis/programs/deskpins.html)?

Comment: DeskPins was so great but the link has died now :(

Comment: The downloadable link can be found here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6194904/2013/DeskPins%201.30%20setup.exe which has been virus-scanned by virustotal here https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/91ed3ff0558bf749fd788bd14b4c54094fbce7dbd1b8c473df5390a8439587a7/analysis/

Answer (score 5):

You could use AutoHotKey!

```
#q::
    WinSet, AlwaysOnTop,,A
Return
```

Would set the currently active window to always on top when you hit winkey and q. If for whatever reason you don't fancy installing AutoHotKey (It's lovely, really!) leave a comment with what hotkey you want, and I can compile a standalone script you can use on any PC :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm using AutoHotKey myself. Just that i haven't installed it since the last format. Tried your file and it works great :D

Comment: @altvali; Glad to help! AHK is something I find it hard to live without, now!